# What is the correct usage of the question mark when using a subsequent parenthesis?

Tags: parentheses

Is this the correct use of the question mark?  Should it be at the end outside of the closing bracket?  See example below

> How do we deliver it? (to the learner)

Answer (score 3):

The question mark marks the end of the question.  If a trailing parenthetical is part of the question, the mark goes after the closing parenthesis:

> How do we deliver it (to the learner)?

If the trailing parenthetical is not part of the question, the parenthetical follows the question mark:

> How do we deliver it? (A very good question, to be sure.)

Comment: What level of obviousness makes a reference unnecessary?  This site has whipped me into giving a reference as a conditioned reflex in an Answer...but I've noticed several instances lately where high-rep users don't.  I would appreciate clarification -- not trying to be snarky, genuinely confused.

Comment: @ab2 You have my prior permission to be genuinely snarky and genuinely confused at the same time.  Nobody likes snark more than I do.   Except perhaps my wife and some of her friends. Oh yes, and Captain Johnson.   Never mind.  You might want to address this question to actual high-rep users, perhaps in meta.  As for me, obviousness is in the eye of the answerer, and I often fail to cite to the merely duplicative or the mostly suspect.  But as sure as the sun rises in the east, someone will be sure to demand a source for that claim.  Probably not much help.  Sorry about that.

Comment: If you insist ... a source, pretty please? / You've added a capital to the subsequent fragment, which validates the structure in all but the most formal writing. // I'm trying to think of a grey area ('Is it or isn't it really part of the question?'). ... An afterthought, an appositive precising the question, perhaps. << How do we deliver it to the learner (to the absolute beginner) >> (Admittedly, I'd probably not use brackets here! 'How do we deliver it to the learner? [...] To the absolute beginner?) But there _must_ be tricky examples.)