# Question mark before or after parentheses for incidental text?

Tags: parentheses, question-mark

I have this sentence:

> Can you share those documents with me?

And I want to add an incidental text like "(no problem if they are in progress)".

Shall I add that text before or after the quastion mark?

> Can you share those documents with me (no problem if they are in progress)?

or

> Can you share those documents with me? (no problem if they are in progress)

or

> Can you share those documents with me? No problem if they are in progress.

**Edit**:
This is not the same topic as in [Where does the question mark go — inside or outside the parentheses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61579/where-does-the-question-mark-go-inside-or-outside-the-parentheses) because in that case, the question was only related to the text inside parantheses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct usage of the question mark when using a subsequent parenthesis?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267657/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-the-question-mark-when-using-a-parenthesis). 'The question mark marks the end of the question. If a trailing parenthetical is part of the question, the mark goes after the closing parenthesis:' (Deadrat) Related: [Where does the question mark go — inside or outside the parentheses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61579/where-does-the-question-mark-go-inside-or-outside-the-parentheses).

Comment: ... In your case, I think the question mark needs to go with the actual question to signal that it is a question, especially if the parenthetical is lengthy. I'd suggest a fragment after: << (No problem if they are in progress.) >>. // Also in the same area: [Using a question mark mid-sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36821/using-a-question-mark-mid-sentence).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the first question you mentioned is pretty similar to my doubt but the answer doesn't give references and seems opinion based. Am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: Not what you're asking, but the statement in parentheses seems open to interpretation: could be taken to mean "no problem, if they are in progress don't worry about sharing them" or "don't worry if they are in progress I'm happy to take them anyway".

Comment: The one appearing first in the comments now I've sorted them out properly is obviously a straight duplicate. The correct procedure is (I believe, still) to add to the original thread rather than to open a duplicate, if you feel the answers there are inadequate. I agree with deadrat's answer, but, as you can see, have requested a supporting reference

Comment: @KillingTime I cited that as a close relative, but it doesn't address sentence-medial question marks.

Comment: Just saying, the parethetical goes right after the noun instead: "Can you share those documents **(no problem if they are in progress)** with me?"

Comment: Folks, this is **not** a duplicate of either of the Questions cited in the comments above.

Comment: If the latter part comes after the question mark (which signifies end of a sentence), why would one **need** paretheses at all? "Can you share those documents with me? No problem if they are in progress."

Comment: @Kris Not a duplicate of 'What is the correct usage of the question mark when using a subsequent parenthesis?'? The best solution is certainly given elsewhere by Andrew Leach: Split it into two sentences. "Can you share those documents with me? There is no problem if they are in progress." And I mention that brackets are a licensed option << "Can you share those documents with me? (There is no problem if they are in progress.)"  >> which is a good way to emphasise non-urgency, and which I'd choose. // "The parenthetical goes right after the noun instead" is merely

Comment: a style choice, and one I'd avoid in favour of two sentences here. // The answer by Andrew, and further discussion, is at [Punctuating a question followed by a further comment in a sentence: position of question mark](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239230/punctuating-a-question-followed-by-a-further-comment-in-a-sentence-position-of/239238#239238).

Comment: Does _the following thread_ provide the answer you require for your question? [Punctuating a question followed by a further comment in a sentence: position of question mark.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239230/punctuating-a-question-followed-by-a-further-comment-in-a-sentence-position-of/239238#239238) << Shall I direct the request to you? In which case I will proceed with sending the email. or Shall I direct the request to you? (In which case I will proceed with sending the email.) or Shall I direct the request to you (in which case I will proceed with sending the email)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thank you very much! Your suggested thread is exactly what I was looking for (and didn't find myself)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Since the OP has found what they need, all's well. Case closed.

Comment: @jimm101, that question is about having a question between parentheses; in this case the question is on the main sentence, the parentheses contain just a comment